# With IE9 i can not see audio player(HTML5 audio tag) in Amazon S3 to upload with iOS

Tags: ios, html, audio, amazon-s3, internet-explorer-9

I uploaded an image file(jpg) and an audio file(m4a) to Amazon S3 with iOS.

With Safari i could see an image and an audio player(HTML5 audio tag) above.
And with IE9 i could see an image, but I can not see an audio player.

I downloaded an image file and an audio file above in Amazon S3 to local computer.
I uploaded this image file and audio file to Amazon S3 from local computer.
So I could see an image and an audio player with Safari and IE9.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I know for a fact that the `<video>` tag does not uniformly support all codecs in all browsers, and I suspect the same is true of audio. IE9's support for the `<audio>` tag is still in beta, and right now the only formats discussed for the web are ogg vorbis, mp3, and wav.

In all likelihood, the reason you can play an m4a in Safari is because of the inclusion of quicktime – with quicktime installed, Safari will play anything in the `<audio>` tag that quicktime can play. This is not true, however, for any other browser combined with quicktime.

Comment: I can see an audio player(m4a/HTML5 audio tag) with Safari and IE9 without QuickTime, when I upload an audio file to Amazon S3 from local computer.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this: "IE9's support for the <audio> tag is still in beta" but IE9 went final five months ago.

Comment: Support for much of HTML5 is still in beta stages – That is, they include functionality on a basic level, but the level of support for specific tags is still poorly supported. http://www.wired.com/epicenter/2010/11/ie9-leads-pack-in-html5-support-not-exactly/ While the information posted here is outdated, my PC at work with current IE9 still ranks in the mid 100s on html5test. HTML5 itself is still not widely supported, and is commonly not recommended for development.